# How to find the right quadrant from Math.atan2 ?

Tags: java

I am using `Math.atan2` to get theta by providing it `Y` and `X` but how do I get the right quadrant?

Is this code correct? I am working with SVG and I need to position the circle in the right quadrant.

```
        double angle = Math.atan2(y, x);

        if (angle >= 0 &&  angle < Math.PI/2  ){
            // 1st
        }

        else if (angle >= Math.PI/2 && angle <  Math.PI) {
            //2nd

        }

        else if (angle >= - Math.PI && angle  < -(Math.PI/2)) {

            //third
        }
        else if (angle >= -(Math.PI/2) && angle < 0) {

        // fourth
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to work as intended apart from a few minor issues.

I'd replace all the `>=` and `<=` with `>` and `<` unless you want to include the axes in your quadrants.

Additionally, if you just want to know where to position the circle, why don't you use your (x,y) pair that you already have? If you have to use polar, then you can just trust `atan2` to give the correct quadrant. However, if you just have to find the quadrant, it doesn't seem like you need to use `atan2` at all since you already have your `x` and `y` values. (You could just check `x>0 && y>0` and say that's the first quadrant, etc.)

Comment: I actually need to use polar

Comment: I think `svg` is sophisticated enough to just be given `(r, theta)`. Why do you need the quadrant?

Comment: I am following an algorithm where I have to position a random circle nearby an existing circle with shortest distance. I have to make sure the angle remains the same. So if the new circle ends up being in the first quadrant I would have to set `x = CX + R * cos (theta)` and `y= CY + R * sin (theta)`, similary if its in the second quadrant I have to set `x = CX - R * cos (theta)` and `y= CY + R * sin(theta)`. It's probably too long to explain here. So I need to know the correct quadrant to do the subtraction when needed. I'm not sure if that's clear, either way I think you answered my equation.

Comment: If you have further inputs, please let me know!

Comment: Well, both `sin` and `cos` are valued from `-1` to `1`, so you can just shove the `theta` and the `sin` and `cos` functions will do your subtraction for you, right?

Comment: I think you are right! Either way you did answer my original question.